# Who can we display, or show, an instance of Excel that is running, and pass in a data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can start a new instance of Excel, like this.

```
from win32com import client
excel=client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
```

I see Excel running in the Windows Task Manager, but I can't actually see Excel in the Task Bar.  I know Excel is running, but I can't interact with it.  How can I display the instance of Excel that is running?  Also, I'd like to be able to write a data frame into that active instance of Excel.  How can I do that?

Thanks!!

Comment: Add `excel.Visible = True`. For the dataframe it may be easier to use pandas `to_excel` to write the excel file before opening the excel application.

Comment: Nice.  It works.  I tried excel.show, and got an error.  The only thing that's kind of weird here, is that it opens Office 365, which I didn't even know I had.  Apparently it's unlicensed too.  There's probably a setting somewhere that controls this behavior.  Anyway, thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(moving comment to answer)

Add `excel.Visible = True` to show the Excel application.

```
from win32com import client
excel=client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = True  # show excel
```

For the dataframe it may be easier to use pandas `to_excel` to write the excel file before opening the excel application.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["A"] = [1,2,3,4,5]
df["B"] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

df.to_excel('data.xlsx', index=False)  # write to Sheet1
```